# PHP - The best substitute to eval

Tags: php

Everybody says that Eval is really dangerous, thats why i'm searching for an alternative.

I'm building a script that allows the user to write his code on a textarea to view the result inside the browser.

I asked here about solutions, and a lot of people said to me that Eval do what i want.

I'm actually using Eval, and it works perfectly well, but is really dangerous because some users can put there some malicious code, and hack all the website, entering on my database, etc, etc...

Resuming, i want to find some substitute to eval, is there any way to build a safer script?

```
<!-- Textarea for the code !-->
Code
<form method="GET">
<textarea name="code">

</textarea>
<input name="code" type="submit" />
</form>
<br>

<!-- Column with the results !-->
Result
<br>
<?php

if(isset($_GET["codebtn"])) {

  eval('?>' . $_GET["code"] .'<?php');

  }
?>
```

Comment: My recommendation to you would to offset the processing of this script onto a disposable virtual instance, preferably jailed into a child directory with just enough requirements to satisfy basic execution. Isolate the code being executed, and then eval is "less harmful", still not harmless, but you can isolate where these evals are being performed

Comment: Agree 100% with above. The only solution is proper jailing, [sandboxing](https://github.com/fieryprophet/php-sandbox). Any other solution will be broken.

Comment: Well this is really the issue with `eval` - it allows users to execute arbitrary code blocks - which is exactly what you're trying to do. Any solution that would work for you here would work for `eval`.

Comment: You could use [phpjs](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs) to build your own evaluator. That way the js wrapped php code wouldn't have access to you php superglobals. It wouldn't ever get to the php binary.

Comment: You need to identify what kind of features you want to eval. Then build a domain specific language (lexer, parser and evaluator) that is compiled down to executable PHP. This allows you to give precise functionalilty and leeway (in terms of security). Building a simple language need not be complex, it's ongoing work. You can write "just enough" to get basic functionality and build it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule `eval` should not be used. Most famously Rasmus Lerdorf, the creator of PHP, said the following:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question.

The reason for this is that usually you are looking for a solution for a specific use-case with limited user input, which can be safely catered for without the use of `eval`.

The exception to this, as in your case, is when you want to create a web based testing area for PHP, where the whole purpose is to run the user's code.

The only way `eval` should be used here is in a completely isolated instance.

There are more sophisticated options available such as using a parser which only allows safe and pre-approved functions to be executed.